# Maping inside a map to render the data matching to the title of the outer map function

Tags: reactjs, json, map-function

I have a a JSON file like the one below:

```
[
{
"category":  "food",
"subcategory": "Snacks",
"eng-name": "Eng name here",
"thai-name": "thai name here",
"description": "Food Description here",
"price": "price per dish or glass",
"price2": "price per bottles",
"tags": "[tags to find type of food or drink (Chicken, vegetarian, vegan, whisky, red wine, chardonnay)]",
"image": "url of img in upload in server"
},
{
"category":  "food",
"subcategory": "Starters",
"eng-name": "Eng name here",
"thai-name": "thai name here",
"description": "Food Description here",
"price": "price per dish or glass",
"price2": "price per bottles",
"tags": "[tags to find type of food or drink (Chicken, vegetarian, vegan, whisky, red wine, chardonnay)]",
"image": "url of img in upload in server"
},
{
"category":  "food",
"subcategory": "Snacks",
"eng-name": "Eng name here",
"thai-name": "thai name here",
"description": "Food Description here",
"price": "price per dish or glass",
"price2": "price per bottles",
"tags": "[tags to find type of food or drink (Chicken, vegetarian, vegan, whisky, red wine, chardonnay)]",
"image": "url of img in upload in server"
}
]
```

What i want to do is to render each subcategory and map inside to render a card with the details of each dish corresponding to the title of each subcategory.
see example in this link:
[Component wanted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXq2d.png)

What is the best way to do it ?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `underscore.js`'s groupBy function to group your data with subcategory. When you get data you can use map on to render card details.

```js
var data = [
{
"category":  "food",
"subcategory": "Snacks",
"eng-name": "Eng name here",
"thai-name": "thai name here",
"description": "Food Description here",
"price": "price per dish or glass",
"price2": "price per bottles",
"tags": "[tags to find type of food or drink (Chicken, vegetarian, vegan, whisky, red wine, chardonnay)]",
"image": "url of img in upload in server"
},
{
"category":  "food",
"subcategory": "Starters",
"eng-name": "Eng name here",
"thai-name": "thai name here",
"description": "Food Description here",
"price": "price per dish or glass",
"price2": "price per bottles",
"tags": "[tags to find type of food or drink (Chicken, vegetarian, vegan, whisky, red wine, chardonnay)]",
"image": "url of img in upload in server"
},
{
"category":  "food",
"subcategory": "Snacks",
"eng-name": "Eng name here",
"thai-name": "thai name here",
"description": "Food Description here",
"price": "price per dish or glass",
"price2": "price per bottles",
"tags": "[tags to find type of food or drink (Chicken, vegetarian, vegan, whisky, red wine, chardonnay)]",
"image": "url of img in upload in server"
}
];
console.log(_.groupBy(data,'subcategory'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.1/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i actually did it by filtering the subcategories then map it in the card component. But i will try with the library that you recommended thank you for the tips

Comment: Dose my suggestion worked?